# How to retrieve the message sent via MainActivity on the App.css page?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

in **MainActivity.cs** I send the following message:

```cs
resultIntent.PutExtra("message", "string123");
```

then in **App.css** i am trying to accept the message as follows:

```cs
Intent.Extras.GetString("message", "");
```

but the path I'm using is for **MainActivity.cs**...

[image]

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: if you want to pass a parameter from MainActivity to App, use a parameter in the App constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to pass a message from **MainActivity** to **App** when the **App** constructor is first created. This you can achieve in a number of ways

### Option 1 (Recommended)

Simply by giving a parameter to **App** constructor as follows

```cs
public App(string message)
{
  InitializeComponent();

  MainPage = new AppShell(message);
}
```

This you can set from **MainActivity** on creation as follows

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

  Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
  global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
  LoadApplication(new App("string123"));
}
```

### Option 2

Yet another option, which i would not prefer, could be to pass an instance of MainActivity to App as follows

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

  this.Intent.PutExtra("message", "string1234");

  Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
  global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
  LoadApplication(new App(this));

}
```

then in App constructor you use this instance as follows

```cs
Android.App.Activity _mainActivity;

public App(object mainActivity)
{
  InitializeComponent();

  string message = "Void";

  if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
  {
    _mainActivity = (Android.App.Activity)mainActivity;
    message = _mainActivity.Intent.Extras.GetString("message", "");
  }

  MainPage = new AppShell(message);
}
```

Comment: I'll check this answer with a tick. It's my fault. I needed to say - "I need to pass a parameter with a local notification". In the notification, I'm going to pass the parameter = "id" (the id of the record in the database). After loading the page with the "id".

Comment: @alexandrf, i see you posted a new question. Consider applying **Option 2** above. In OnResume you should be able to call `message = _mainActivity.Intent.Extras.GetString("message", "");`

Comment: yes. ths. now i can call ``````message = _mainActivity.Intent.Extras.GetString("message", ""); ``````But in MainActivity.cs i see this: in function ``````LoadApplication(new App()); ``````  ***CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'mainActivity' of 'App.App(object)'***

Comment: @alexandrf, please see definition of `OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` in my answer above, under **Option 2** section (there you will see you have to write `new App(this)`)

Comment: yes, i saw. but thank you for correcting the comment, I might well not have seen it. thank you for helping me all this time.