# How to retrieve the message sent via AppDelegate.cs on the App.css page?

Tags: xamarin.forms

in **AppDelegate.cs** I send the following message:

```
this.SetValueForKey(new NSString("text"), new NSString("key"));
LoadApplication(new App(this));
```

I would like to get the values in the OnResume method. Is it possible?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  The example you give is just some arbitrary hardcoded values.  Where is this "message" data coming from?  What is the use case?

Comment: @Jason my goal is to open a certain page after clicking on a local notification. I think that passing a message to "setvalue" is not the best option. So I asked another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69326942/how-do-i-get-the-value-from-the-notification-after-clicking-on-the-notification

Comment: @Jason I recognized you on the topic(further). After the task is implemented (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69202613/how-to-retrieve-the-message-sent-via-mainactivity-on-the-app-css-page/69203411#69203411 ) in which I get the article ID in "onResume". Next, I implemented the Xamarin functionality.Essentials: MediaPicker and as it turned out, after the user selects the image, the "onResume" method is called. So after selecting the image, the article ID is loaded for me. The article should not be loaded.

Comment: @Jason The user must continue to work in the area where he was, and he is redirected to the article. I couldn't implement the correct logic. This is for Android. So I say - I think that passing a message to "setvalue" is not the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a test about sending message from Appdelegate to App, and it works fine.
Here are the steps below:

First, create a dictionary in app:

```
    public partial class App : Application
        {
            public static Dictionary<int,string> dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            public App()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    
               .
               .
               .
            }
```

Second, add message into the dic in Appdelegate:

```
 public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            App.dic.Add(1, "Hello");
            App.dic.Add(2, "World"); 
            App.dic.Add(3, "!");

            LoadApplication(new App());

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
```

At last, print the message in the onresume method:

```
 protected override void OnResume()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string>kvp in dic)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value);
        }
    }
```

And the result is here:

[image]