# How do I get the value from the notification after clicking on the notification in the onResume method in the App.cs class?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am creating a notification in MyApp.iOS (/Services/NotifyServices.cs)

```
 var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier(requestID, content, trigger);
```

All code:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.GetNotificationSettings((settings) =>
            {
                var alertsAllowed = (settings.AlertSetting == UNNotificationSetting.Enabled);
                if (alertsAllowed == true)
                {
                    var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent();
                    content.Title = item.Text;
                    content.Body = item.Description;
                    content.Badge = 1;
                    

                    var trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(1, false);

                    var requestID = item.Id.ToString();
                    var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier(requestID, content, trigger);

                    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest(request, (err) =>
                    {
                        if (err != null)
                        {
                            // Do something with error...
                        }
                    });
                }
```

I would like to get the value of the variable "RequestId" in "App.cs" in the"onResume" method. Is it possible? How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use Messaging Center to pass value between multiple projects.

#### iOS

```cs
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
         global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
         LoadApplication(new App());
         global::Xamarin.Forms.FormsMaterial.Init();

         UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = new MyDelegate();
         return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }

public class MyDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    {
        public override void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
        {
            var id = response.Notification.Request.Identifier;
            MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "Hi", id);
        }
    }
```

#### Forms

Get the id in App constructor.

```cs
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage( new Page2());


        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, string>(this, "Hi", (obj,str) => {
                var id = str;
        });
    }
```